# PHP MySQL: How to get result from prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $conn = new mysqli(.....);
 $param = $_GET['manf'];

 $stmt = $conn->prepare('select manf from manf where manf = ?');
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();

 echo $stmt->num_rows;

 $result = $stmt->get_result();

 if(!$result){
     die(mysql_error());
 }
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo $row['manf'];
 }
```

`echo $stmt->num_rows` prints right vaule however I can't get results from while statement. I also tried `mysqli::bind_result` but didn't work.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably not related, but `die(mysql_error())` won't work in this code - you'd need to use `die($stmt->error)` instead.

Comment: yes im expecting multiple rows

Comment: I find your code to be nonsensical.   If your sql is `select manf from manf where manf = ?`, then every row in the result set will be the exact `manf` value that you bound to the prepared statement.  At most, your query should be fetching a single row with the `COUNT(1)`, otherwise it is just code for coding sake.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$conn = new mysqli(.....);
$param = $_GET['manf'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare('select manf from manf where manf = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($result);

echo $stmt->num_rows;

while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo $result;
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

for fetching you need to use `$stmt->fetch()`.

Comment: Unfortunately this also prints nothing ㅠㅠ

Comment: are you expecting multiple results from the query?